# How do I solve the error in locating the word file?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I am trying to open the location of the word file it is giving the following error. While debugging i found the error in the following location. I am newbee for the VBA can someone help me out

[image]

My code is

```
sub findBearingCopyFromExcel()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim aCell As Range, rng As Range
    Dim SearchString As String
Set rng = Range("A750:A1790")
SearchString = "(248_R), 38,7 %"

For Each aCell In rng
    If InStr(1, aCell.Value, SearchString, vbTextCompare) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(aCell.row + 4, 1), Cells(aCell.row + 9, 6)).Copy
Exit Sub
        Else: End If
    Next aCell
End Sub
Sub bearingDataFromExcelToWord()
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdoc As Word.Document
Set wdoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open("E:\ShareDrive_Ruehl\full-flexible-MBS-models_report\example-report\FullFlexibleGearbox - Copy.docx")

wrdApp.Visible = True
With wdoc
.Application.Selection.Find.Text = "(248_R), 38,7 %"
.Application.Selection.Find.Execute


.Application.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
    .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Application.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
    .Application.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    .Application.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=wdLine, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend
    .Application.Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=5, Extend:=wdExtend
    .Application.Selection.Paste
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Side note: Please always embed code as text code block (not as an image), so people can copy and fix it easily.

Comment: @Peh Thanks for the feedback. I have added the code too. I just wanted to show where exactly I found the error and also the error box. Kindly let me know if this correction could help me solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

`wrdApp` is not created add `new` to its definition or set it as new later, but before you use it.

Comment: Thanks @Nathan_Sav. Now I am getting another error. "Microsoft excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action". Could you check what it is for?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `wrdApp`.

```
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
    wrdApp.Visible = True

Dim wdoc as Word.Document
Set wdoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(...)
```

Comment: Thanks  it help me to solve that error. But now I am getting another error.
"Microsoft excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"

Answer (score 0):

At a guess it's hanging on opening the document - are you sure you have the right path and filename?
Move

```
 wrdApp.Visible = True
```

to before the "Set Wdoc..." line and check if the file is opened

Comment: Yes. @Harassed Dad. Location is right. I tried ur suggestion. But it is showing as "User defined type not defined". compile error

Comment: What line is highlighted when it gives the compile error?

Comment: I have worked further and have got this result. could you please have a look at this problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45275980/how-to-insert-data-copied-from-an-excel-sheet-to-the-table-existing-in-the-word